# Phoenix channels, set maximum amount of users per channel

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have simple chat app created with Elixir+Phoenix and now it's like - everyone can join one single room. But I want to make it work like: user enters his username, chat says to him, that he should wait a bit for another user to join and it connects two random users, who is in queue. I can implement user authentication, but I have no idea how to create this functionality. I've searched documentation for something similar, but I have not found an answer.

Comment: You are probably going to want to look into [Phoenix.Presence](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html). There is no other way (without implementing something yourself) to track the number of users in a channel.

Answer (score -1):

There are a good lecture about Phoenix, WebSockets and chat application

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdLJvuQkTNE